# ssh in korn script gives 'stty: tcgetattr: A specified file does not support the ioctl system call.'

Tags: ssh, ksh, sudo, aix

I have a command that works successfully when executing via a putty window connected to an AIX box.

```
ssh -T user@host 'sudo /path/to/command argument1'
```

However, when I build that command in a script based on asking for user and host, it gives me this error.

```
ksh: sudo /path/to/command argument1:  not found.
```

I have my script set to output its commands as it runs.

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
```

This is the text in the script that ultimately gives the output above -

```
ssh -T $(whoami)@$server "'"$userid $script$action"'"
```

And this is what outputs from that script text (its identical to calling it outside script) -

```
ssh -T user@host 'sudo /path/to/command argument1'
```

Is there some difference in the way this is executing?

Update:

I changed my script to just connect without executing and I get the following error, but it still connects. -

```
ssh -T user@host
user@host's password:
stty: tcgetattr: A specified file does not support the ioctl system call.
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your command to run on the remote server in double quotes:

```
ssh -T $(whoami)@$server "$userid $script$action"
```

More info from the AIX [site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_quote_chars.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, although I would love an explanation. Removing the single quotes from the script made it work.

Works from script and outside script:

```
ssh -T $(whoami)@$server $userid $script$action
```

Doesn't work for script, but works outside script:

```
ssh -T $(whoami)@$server "'"$userid $script$action"'"
```